# Set Authorization header during form submit

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a form and want to set authorization header during form submit.
This is the code

```
  var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            standardSubmit: true,
            url           : url,
            method        : method
        });

        // Call the submit to begin the file download.
        form.submit({
            target : '_blank', 
            params : params,
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
            }

        });
```

But when I check headers in Network, the "Authorization" header is not being set on the request.
Can someone help what I am doing wrong?

PS. This is not file upload.

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2bkr 

It sent headers.

Comment: `target : '_blank', ` what is that line for??